# AngularJS service that uses multiple $http.get

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to learn AngularJS and I have the following service that works, but I'm wondering if there's a better way of writing it that is simpler and involves less duplication of code. Can you think of anything?

The service:

```
app.service("myService", function ($http) {
    this.callData1 = function () {
        var url = myurl1;
        function getData() {
            return $http.get(url);
        }
        return {
            getData: getData,
        }
    },
    this.callData2 = function () {
        var url = myurl2;
        function getData() {
            return $http.get(url);
        }
        return {
            getData: getData,
        }
    },
    this.callData3 = function () {
        var url = myurl3;
        function getData(var1, var2) {
            return $http({
                url: url,
                method: "GET",
                params: { var1: var1, var2: var2 }
            });
        }
        return {
            getData: getData,
        }
    }
});
```

My controller:

```
app.controller("myController", function ($scope, myService) {
    myService.callData1().getData().then(function (response) {
        $scope.var1 = response.data;
    });
    myService.callData2().getData().then(function (response) {
        $scope.var2 = response.data;
    });
    var var1 = "something";
    var var2 = "something else";
    myService.callData3().getData(var1, var2).then(function (response) {
        $scope.var3 = response.data;
    });
});
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but why learning [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) and not [Angular](https://angular.io/) ? AngularJS is the V1, and Angular is actually in V11.

Comment: Quote from https://angularjs.org : "This site and all of its contents are referring to AngularJS (version 1.x), if you are looking for the latest Angular, please visit angular.io."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generalize it as follows:

```
app.service("myService", function ($http) {
    this.getData = function(url, method, params){
        var httpParams = {
            url: url,
            method: method || "GET", // If method is skipped, use "GET" by default
            params: params || {} // If no params are given, take {}
        };
        return $http.get(httpParams);
    };
});
```

And in controller, you can use this service as follows:

```
app.controller("myController", function ($scope, myService) {
    var url = "https://blahblah";
    myService.getData(url).then(function (response) {
        $scope.var1 = response.data;
    });
    var params = {var1: "something", var2: "something2"};
    myService.getData(url, "POST", params).then(function (response) {
        $scope.var1 = response.data;
    });
});
```